# Error in ImportXML on Google Sheet

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm getting no data back when trying to figure out an ImportXML statement to acquire some table data from a website into my Google Sheet.  The source code for website is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di7PN.jpg).  The specific data I'm after is the data within div class = "live-prices".  I'd like to get all of that, including the table.  I've tried this statement: =IMPORTXML(A4,"//div[@class='live-prices']") only to receive an "Imported content is empty" error.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Still seeing information on this.  Thanks!

Comment: can you share the actual link instead of an image of the html? it's far easier to actually test the xpaths on the actual site your trying to import.

Comment: the first argument of importxml is the URL of the XML, is that really A4 ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this on my own -- turned out it wasn't returning because it required an authorization.